# Is there a way to extract PE ratio from yfinance?

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am trying to build a stock screener that extracts data from yahoo finance using yfinance. Is there a way to extract the PE ratio using yfinance in python.

Comment: Are you okay with web scraping from yahoo finance? also which company's PE ratio you want to get? I have previously done web scraping from yahoo finance using beautifulsoup

Comment: I am currently trying to make a program that generates the PE ratio of all the companies within certain range. For ex: All the companies with PE ratio ranging from 15 - 25.

Comment: Have you tried `ticker.info['forwardPE']`?

Comment: yes i have, that doesn't seem to work